# D3.JS conditional tooltip html

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have dots in a D3JS scatter plot.

Tooltips work fine with this code:

```
 // draw dots
  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 7)
      .attr("cx", xMap)
      .attr("cy", yMap)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(cValue(d));}) 
      .style("opacity", .95)
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(100)
               .style("opacity", .95);
          tooltip.html(" Seen on : " + d.url)
               .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + 10 + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) - 200 + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(200)
               .style("opacity", 0);
      })
      .style("cursor", 'pointer')                              
      .on('click', function(d) {
          var url = d.url;
          window.open(url); });
```

But I want to include a if...else statement to better customize the inner html of the tooltip. So I tried:

```
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
               .duration(100)
               .style("opacity", .95);
          tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + 10 + "px")
               .style("top", (d3.event.pageY) - 200 + "px")
               .html(   if (d.category == "A") {return " Oh yeah ! Seen on : " + d.url"}
            else { return " So cool ! Check it out on : " + d.url"};)
      ;})
```

But I get the following error in Firebug console :

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'if'
```

Comment: this line is wrong `.html(   if (d.category == "A") {return " Oh yeah ! Seen on : " + d.url"}` ... use a function instead ... or use conditional operator ... read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 is a kind of magic but you're still writing JS : you can't write a statement where an expression is expected. Wrap that in a function,

```
tooltip.html(function() { 
    if (d.category == "A") {
        return " Oh yeah ! Seen on : " + d.url;
    } else { 
        return " So cool ! Check it out on : " + d.url;
    }
})
```

Or use a ternary operator

```
tooltip.html((d.category == "A") ? "":"")
```

or a variable

```
var html = (d.category == "A") ? "":"";
tooltip.html(html);
```

Note: be careful with your quotes, the syntax highlighter can help you to spot the mismatches.